# Modify an SQL column only on creating new records

Tags: activerecord, yii

`seq` is an integer column in a DB table.

I want a CActiveRecord derived class which would do `seq=MAX(seq)+1` in SQL on creating a new record and would not modify the `seq` column on update an existing record.

How?

Comment: You sure you want to do that? How are you going to deal with concurrent inserts?

Comment: why not use auto increment ? And which dbms you are using ?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Concurrent inserts are no problem because I use transaction-capable InnoDB and INSERT statements are processed in an (implied) transaction

Comment: @sakhunzai I use auto increment for an other purpose that is for creating IDs of newly inserted rows, but I need user-editable field seq for sorting of the rows by the user. It is not the same as row ID (autoincremented). I use MySQL with InnoDB.

Comment: So the lock that gets put on the table / index to get the max doesn't concern you? It would me.

Comment: What are you ordering the whole table, or a group within it e.g InvoiceLines by InvoiceID? There's a better way for both.

Answer (score 0):

Since the whole business logic is not clear but somehow from above discussion this could be your solution:

Add following two functions to the desired model class and you are done !

```
public function beforeSave(){
 if($this->isNewRecord){
   $this->seq=$this->getNextSeq();
  }

  return parent::beforeSave();
}

public function getNextSeq(){
  $maxSeq = $this->findBySql('select max(seq)+1 as seq from ' . $this->tableName(), array());
  return (!$maxSeq->seq ? 1 : $maxSeq->seq); 
}
```

**Just a side note**

If you are using mysql the last function could be optimized (when table is empty) e.g

```
 public function getNextSeq(){
      $maxSeq = $this->findBySql('select coalesce(max(seq),0)+1 as seq from ' . $this->tableName(), array());
      return $maxSeq->seq; 
    }
```

I am not sure if `coalesce` function is supported by other DBMS.